# Finding the probability that a pair of balls will contain both blue and brown balls.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two set of balls are placed side to side. The first set has a chance of $m/n$ on being blue and the second set has a chance of $p/n$ on being brown. When I say side to side, I say this suppose you have $n$ set of balls and you place them in a line and you also got another set of $n$ balls and you place them parallel to the first set and hence in a line too. So each ball of the first set forms a pair with the corresponding ball on the second set. So what will be the probability that such a pair contain both blue and brown ball?

Comment: Are the balls in the first set either blue or non-blue (more importantly, non-brown)?

Comment: Would the following be the exact same question?

>Imagine you have a $2\times n$ array of lights.  In the first row, $m$ lights are on, and in the second row, $p$ lights are on.  What is the probability that you choose a column where both lights are on?

Answer (score 0):

If $m+p{\gt}n$ then the probability will be 1 because of the pigeonhole principle.

When $m+p{\le}n$,

Total number of possible cases = ${n\choose m}{n\choose p}$

Number of cases where there is both blue and brown will be = 
$\sum_{i=1}^n{n-i\choose n-m+i}{n-i\choose n-p+i}$

I leave the simplification to you. Dividing these two will give the required probability